# Stopping a nohup Java process that is reading MQ

Tags: java, unix, mq, nohup

I have a java process that runs in nohup which reads the message from MQ continuously. What is the best way to stop that process in a controlled manner instead of killing the process to stop abruptly.

Currently I have coded to match the incoming message with "STOP_THE_PROCESS" string and if it matches it will stop the process. Is there any other better way?

Comment: A [`SIGHUP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) is the same as `kill -1`. Running `nohup` means the process ignores `HUP` (or `1`). Use [`TERM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_(command)#Examples) (or `15`); see also `man kill` and [Signals Used in Oracle Solaris, Linux, and macOS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/troubleshoot/handle-signals-and-exceptions.htm#JSTGD356)

Comment: Which type of MQ do you connect to?

Comment: IBM MQ using pmo and gmo

Answer (score 0):

You can add so called 'shutdown port' to your java application: application will listen on specific port for shutdown command and terminate gracefully on receive.

Apache Tomcat uses this approach, with dedicated tcp socket.

Sample JMX-based implementation: https://dzone.com/articles/java-jmx-shutdown-example